# How to delete collected data inside the stream in Java?

Tags: java, stream

I have a repository method, that delete list of data (`removeListIds(List<Long> ids`)). The stream after doing his work collects the data. I need to delete this collected data inside the stream, does it possible?

```
list1.stream()
             .flatMap(mc->mc.getQuestions().stream()                                    
             .map(Question::getQuestionId)) .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I tried this:

```
   list1.stream()
                 .flatMap(mc->mc.getQuestions().stream()                                    
                 .map(Question::getQuestionId)) .collect(Collectors.toList()).map(list->removeListIds(list);
```

How to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

No easy way to do it with what you have now. Don't try to continue. Instead do it the right way and convert the `removeListIds(List<Long> ids)` method into a predicate that rejects the identifiers that are to be removed:

```
public boolean removeId(Long id) {
    // your code here
}

list1.stream()
    .flatMap(mc->mc.getQuestions().stream())
    .map(Question::getQuestionId)
    .filter(id -> removeId(id)) 
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks you, Torben, for response, but I don't need to collect the result, just remove after collected data

Comment: You probably need to try to improve your question a bit. It seems that your question does not match the code.

Comment: @G T you seems to be confused here or the question is not correct
You need to remove elements from original list and collect the matched data in new list?
Something like that?

Comment: I want to collect data in stream and using the method removeListIds(List<Long> ids) to delete the collected data inside the steam

Comment: Why above code oes not work for you then, it does that job for you
Are you saying ater collecting data you need to empty the list? You also did not specify the condition you need to remove the IDs

Answer (score 0):

You can do a filter:

```
list1.stream()
   .flatMap(mc->mc.getQuestions().stream()                                    
       .map(Question::getQuestionId))
   .filter(x -> !listOfIdToRemove.contains(x))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```